# msal redirect call back is not getting called in Cordova app

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am creating a mobile app using Cordova version 9. I use msal.js (v1.3.0) library for authentication with Azure AD B2C.
This is my *msal* configuration for the instance `const myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);`

```
const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: "1234",
    authority: ''url,
    validateAuthority: false,
    redirectUri: 'msauth.[budleID]://auth'
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "localStorage", // This configures where your cache will be stored
    storeAuthStateInCookie: false
  }
};
```

From the Cordova application (iOS) on clicking login, Safari browsers open up. After i enter the credentials, I am able to redirect back to the app. but the redirect callback handler `myMSALObj.handleRedirectCallback(authRedirectCallBack);` is not getting triggered.

How to trigger the handler and whether the redirecturi formate for Cordova app is correct?

Comment: Did you have any luck with getting this to work?

Comment: Not exactly. But [Cordova Plugin Custom-URL-scheme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme) might help.